# Switch to root user always failed after modifying /etc/pam.d/common-password

Tags: password, root, authentication, pam

I'm using ubuntu 18.04. To strengthen my pass-word policy I modify my `/etc/pam.d/common-password` like this:

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
#password       requisite                       pam_cracklib.so retry=3 minlen=8 difok=3
password requisite pam_cracklib.so retry=3 minlen=8 difok=3 ucredit=-1 lcredit=-1 dcredit=-1
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512 remember=15
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
password        requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
password        required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

At first when I tried to login to root using `sudo -s` there is no problem at all, but when I tried to login to root using `sudo -s` and entered my password I always get **Sorry, try again.**

Answer (score 2):

The `password` lines in PAM configuration only take effect *when you're trying to change your password*. So your `/etc/pam.d/common-password` modification is extremely unlikely to be a factor in you not being able to switch to root using `sudo`.

If you had made any changes to PAM configuration lines beginning with keywords `auth`, `account`, or `session`, then it would be possible for your changes to have caused `sudo` to fail.

The `auth` lines tell the system how the identity of the user attempting to log in should be verified. ("How do I know it's you?")

The `account` lines deal with determining whether or not you will be allowed in once you've successfully authenticated: are there login time restrictions for you? Possibly a limit for a maximum number of consecutive logins per user? Is your account restricted to local logins only? Has the administrator blocked regular user logins with an `/etc/nologin` file (perhaps in order to get some major OS upgrade or disk space restructuring done)?

Once these checks have been passed, the `session` lines define the basic things the system needs to do to set up your session: things like applying `ulimit` restrictions, setting up a basic set of environment variables, recording your session to the `utmp` file, possibly granting you access to some hardware devices only if you are logging in locally.